# Frage über Personalpronomen und Pronominaladverbien

Tags: pronoun, personal-pronoun, pronominal-adverb

Im Buch "Die große deutsche Lernergrammatik" steht under "Der Gebrauch von Personalpronomen" (§118)

> Bei der Verwendung eines Personalpronomens zusammen mit einer Präposition ist besondere Vorsicht geboten... Wenn ... das Pronomen auf eine Sache hinweist, verwendet man das entsprechende Pronomialadverb: *Wir machen jedes Jahr eine **Urlaubsreise**.  Wir geben zwar **dafür** ... viel Geld aus, aber **sie** macht uns viel Spaß.*

und unter "Pronominaladverbien" (§174) steht:

> Die Pronominaladverbien ersetzen immer einen Satzteil, der sich aus „Präposition + Nomen" zusammengesetzt und im Satz die Funktion eines Präpositionalobjekts oder einer adverbialen Bestimmung hat. Allerdings darf das Nomen keine Person, sondern ausschließlich eine Sache benennen: *Die Karten?  Natürlich habe ich **daran** (= an die Karten) gedacht; In der Mitte steht ein Tisch und **darauf** (= auf dem Tisch) eine Vase.*

Ich habe alles dies vorher gelernt, und glaubte, dass ich es verstanden hatte, aber mir kommt das, was das Buch hier behauptet, wie neue Information vor.  Meines Erachtens, war es so, das man "wo" und "da" nur mit etwas Unbestimmtem, oder mit etwas, was sich nicht auf etwas Bestimmtes bezieht, benutzen würde:

> Ich brauche etwas, womit ich mein Haus putzen kann.

Sonst, glaubte ich, benutzte man in solchen Situationen Personalpronomen, nicht Pronominaladverbien, im Gegensatz zu dem, was das Buch behauptet -- oder, zumindest, wäre es nicht *inkorrekt*, das zu machen:

> In der Mitte steht **ein Tisch** und auf **ihm** eine Vase.

> Diese sind **die Leute**, mit **denen** wir nach England gehen werden.

Täusche ich mich? War es immer so, dass man mit Präpositionen und Personalpronomen ein Pronominaladverb benutzen musste?  (Ich gebe zu, dass das Buch eine Voraussetzung bemerkt, die ich nicht völlig verstehe: "... im Satz die Funktion eines Präpositionalobjekts oder einer adverbialen Bestimmung")

Ich bin, letztendlich, ein bisschen verwirrt!

Answer (score 1):

> In der Mitte steht ein Tisch und auf ihm eine Vase.

Das ist akzeptabel, aber die Variante

> In der Mitte steht ein Tisch und darauf eine Vase.

ist gängiger.

---

> Dies<strike>e</strike> sind die Leute, mit denen wir nach England gehen werden.

Hier gibt es ohnehin keine Möglichkeit, ein da-Wort zu verwenden, weil das Pronominaladverb *damit* nicht auf Personen als Begleiter verweist, sondern auf Begleitumstände oder Gründe:

> Es ergab sich damit (mit den zuvor genannten Umständen) ein Problem.